# SugarCrm 6.5 CE: how to change the logic of merge multiple roles

Tags: acl, sugarcrm

As default, when a user belongs to multiple roles, the more restrictive setting prevails.

Refer to this scenario: I have twenty users and I want to grant the access to one particular module (i.e. Ticket) to only one user. For the default logic, I should assign to nineteen users a particular role that block the access to that module.

I think that is more intuitive if there is a simple way to alter the ACL system so that the less restrictive setting prevails. In this way I could assign a role only to the one user that I want to guarantee the access.

So, the question is: how to accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way out of the box. There is a solution called [SecuritySuite](https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/securitysuite/) where it works exactly the way you want. If they belong to multiple roles then the most permissive rights are applied. There is a global setting to turn it back to restrictive as well.

Comment: Unfortunately this is no a free (or cheap) solution.

Comment: That is correct on the free part. Cheap is relative though so I don't agree there.